# Spring Integration - how to pass parameters into the method of service activator

Tags: spring-integration

I need to pass the parameter in the method called via service-activator. I am able to successfully do this with the help of header-enricher. Below is the working code snippet.

```
<int:chain input-channel="inChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="routeName" value="TestRoute" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:service-activator ref="customLoggingRoute"
        method="logRoute">
    </int:service-activator>
</int:chain>


public Message logRoute(Message m, @Header("routeName") String routeName) {
    System.out.println("Inside route: " + routeName);
    return m;
}
```

But I dont want to add anything to header. Is there any alternative by which we can accomplish the same thing without header-enricher.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no. The Spring Integration contract for invokers is Messaging. So, when we have only a message in between, there is nothing more we can utilize. You can have a complex `payload` object and transfer data through it, or move your data into headers.

Of course you can consider to use a `ThreadLocal` since we are in Java and as long as your flow is in the same thread, but this is going to be slightly overhead.

I think you need to start from the theory of the Messaging and come back to us when you understand all those restrictions.

https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Comment: Thanks Artem for your quick response.